# search for duplicated consecutive rows and put in additional column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df1
a  b  c  d
0  2  4  1
0  2  5  1
0  1  6  2
1  2  7  2
1  1  8  1
1  1  4  1
```

I need to group by a and b and if two consecutive values in d are = 1 within groups, I want c in a column next to the row . Like:

```
df1
a  b  c  d   c1 
0  2  4  1   5
0  1  6  2   nan  
1  2  7  2   nan 
1  1  8  1   4
```

Any ideas?
I tried

```
df1.groupby([df1.a, df1.b, d.diff().ne(0)]
```

then `loc()` only the rows with 1s and merge the two dataframes again, but the first function is not completely correct.

Comment: And what have you tried? Please add your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there. I will take off my downvote once you do that.

Comment: did it, thank you. It should be a combination with df1.groupby(), df1.d==df1.d.shift(1), df1.loc[df1['d'] == 1], merge()